# Primary menu background color change in wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, background-color

I want to change primary color of my wordpress website ( http://jodhpurhomeservices.com/ )from #FBD232 to #00C700 . Which CSS code should i use to change color of primary color?

Thanks

Comment: in chrome and firefox you can right-click and select Inspect Element from the context menu, the inspector will help you find the class and the file where the class is defined. think about theme updates before making changes. For a one line change, you can just make a note of it. For more extensive changes look into child themes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-navigation, .header02 #site-navigation .menu, .header02 #site-navigation .primary-menu::before {
    background-color: #00c700;
}
.header02 #site-navigation .menu::before, .header02 #site-navigation .menu > ul > li::before, .header02 #site-navigation .menu > li::before {
    border-left-color: #00c700;
}

#site-navigation .menu > ul > li, #site-navigation .menu > li {
    background-color: #00c700;
}

.header02 #site-navigation .menu::before, .header02 #site-navigation .menu > ul > li::before, .header02 #site-navigation .menu > li::before {
    border-left-color: #000000;
}

.site-footer .social-menu .menu::after, .site-footer .social-menu .menu .menu-item::after {
    border-left-color: #000000;
}

a.button, button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"], .btn, .thememove-btn {
    background-color: #00c700;
}
```

```html
replace this css
```